# How can I delay my API Request in Rest Assured?

Tags: delay, rest-assured

Making a POST call (RESTful) - which updates some record in Data Base
and during this call it will lock that particular record in the DB.

So, I need to delay my request and during this delay I have to verify the data base table.

Comment: https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/29379/how-to-wait-for-an-api-request-to-return-a-response please check this

Comment: Thanks Manoj, i cant use connection timeout , when API disconnects with server it release all the locks it holding , so cant really get to see the lock in DB